# Apps Not Showing in Settings on iPhone in iOS 15.2

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

I updated my iOS to (iOS 15.2.1) after that I did not receive notification from WhatsApp.
I opened the notification bar in setting but I can't find WhatsApp there
I did multiple things (reboot all settings - restart my iPhone...) but nothing helped.
Does anyone know what I should do without deleting the app and reinstalling it?

Comment: Try iOS 15.3, recently released.

Comment: @lhf I updated it, but still did not work.
WhatsApp app not found in notifications.