# WhatsApp Not Showing in Notification's settings on iPhone in iOS 15.3

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, whatsapp.app

[image]

I asked the same question at ([Apps Not Showing in Settings on iPhone in iOS 15.2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436279/apps-not-showing-in-settings-on-iphone-in-ios-15-2)), but no one knows the answer.
I have a bad problem, please can anyone help me?
I update it to iOS 15.3 and nothing happened.
My phone is showing this message but I can't find this path on my iPhone (I don't have WhatsApp in notifications in setting)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you update your iOS

Comment: Isn't there WhatsApp in Settings > Notifications? I saw your comment but I find that weird. Maybe try searching in the Settings searchbar for "WhatsApp".

Comment: Did you ever get prompted by WhatsApp to allow notifications? Apps will appear in Settings when they prompt you for some informations which could then be configured in Settings, such as microphone or camera permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can access these settings in two different ways:

- Open settings app -> scroll down to WhatsApp -> select Notifications -> turn on notifications for WhatsApp

[image: lel]

- Open settings app -> scroll to Notifications -> scroll to WhatsApp -> turn on WhatsApp notifications

[image: So n ding is das]

If neither show up then something is wrong with your WhatsApp installation. **Make a backup (of the WhatsApp chats!)**, delete the app, and reinstall.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the WhatsApp application does not appear for me in notifications bar, (scroll to WhatsApp) there is no WhatsApp there and I do not know why.
And I am not in my country so I can not activate WhatsApp again, I can not delete it and reinstall it.

Comment: Did you try the second method?

Comment: yes, but also I did not found the WhatsApp application

Comment: also, in iOS 15.3 there is no notification bar in WhatsApp .
I mean the first method is not valid anymore

Comment: something isnt adding up here. I have iOS 15.3 installed. You have to open the iPhone settings app (go to your home screen and find the settings https://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/iOS-Settings-app-icon.jpg) and not in the WhatsApp app.

Comment: I edit the question to show you that there is no notification bar in the second pic
and there is no WhatsApp application in the third pic

Comment: I see, that is weird and I fear that there is no easy fix for that. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem here, so I can't help.